# Looking for one Google Script App for 4 sheet tabs to produce one json

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok...not sure how to do this.  Right now I 4 sheets and 4 scripts for each sheet producing 4 json feeds.  What I am trying to experiment with is having one script that will produce 1 json that I can use in a web page and just call the type of class.  They are all formatted the same with columns etc.

Here is the Google Script App code I have.

```
    function doGet(e){

 // Change Spread Sheet url
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SpreadsheetID/edit#gid=0");

// Sheet Name, Change Sheet to whatever name you used to name your sheet
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Class Sheet 1");

 return getClasses(sheet); 

}

function getClasses(sheet){
  var dataObj = {};
  var dataArray = [];

// collecting data starting from 2nd Row , 1st column to last row and last column
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, 1]).getValues();

  for(var i = 0, l= rows.length; i<l ; i++){
    var dataRow = rows[i];
    var record = {};

    record['Name'] = dataRow[0];
    record['Note'] = dataRow[1];
    record['Address'] = dataRow[2];
    record['StreetAddress'] = dataRow[3];
    record['City'] = dataRow[4];
    record['State'] = dataRow[5];
    record['ZipCode'] = dataRow[6];
    record['ContactName'] = dataRow[7];
    record['EMailAddress'] = dataRow[8];
    record['CustomerServicePhone'] = dataRow[9];

    dataArray.push(record);

  }

  dataObj = dataArray;

  var result = JSON.stringify(dataObj);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

 }
```

Scratching my head on this a little bit....I'm sure its something simple and I am probably over thinking things, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read [mcve] and [ask]. Your post lacks necessary information- To begin with, What's the problem with the code? What error(s), if any did you get?  What did you expect and what actually happened?

Comment: Right...nothing wrong with the code the way it is written so there is no error.  Problem I am having is figuring out how I can use this one code for multiple sheets and have it output the appropriate json feed without having to maintain 4 scripts for different Online or Classroom Classes..  Right now its tied to one sheet.  That's what I am stuck on.

Comment: Maybe I can explain it this way.  
Currently I have Class Sheet 1, Class Sheet 2, Class Sheet3 and Class Sheet 4 along with Class Script 1, Class Script 2, Class Script 3 and Class Script 4 which produces Class JSON 1, Class JSON 2, CLass JSON 3. and Class JSON 4.
Looking to make Class Script 1, Class Script 2, Class Script 3 and Class Script 4 into just one script called Class Script ALL
Class Script ALL will produce Class JSON 1, Class JSON 2, Class JSON 3 and Class JSON 4 or it can produce just one JSON but separate the Classes in the JSON by the sheet name.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: [Edit] your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible Solution:

The `e` object in your [`doGet(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) provides a way to send parameters to your script. You can access different sheets with different url parameters. You can then easily get the  requested SheetName through `e.parameter`. Use

```
https://script.google.com/.../exec?sheet=ClassSheet1 //for ClassSheet1
https://script.google.com/.../exec?sheet=ClassSheet2 //for ClassSheet2
```

#### Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SpreadsheetID/edit#gid=0");
 var sheetName = e.parameter.sheet;
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
 return getClasses(sheet); 
}
```

You can also provide UI in your web-app to select a sheet.